# Get the size of several web pages at once with iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to create an application to check whether some websites are available or not and to have direct access to them.

I have made a Master/Detail application. In the Master View i have the list of all web sites i want to check and if i tap on one, i am sent to the Detail view with a `Web View` on this site.

It works great.

But i would like to show on each line of the table view the size of the home page of the site.

I have tried and managed to get the size of a web page with `NSURLConnection` and the `didReceiveData` and `didFinishLoading` method.

But how can i do to launch several simultaneous `NSURLConnection` to grab all sizes ?
Or maybe there is an easier way with NSURLRequest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `NSOperation` and queue each operation to `NSOperationQueue`, add each download url operation to OperationQueue.

---

Or

Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library

---

or `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`

Comment: Thanks for the tips .. i will try AFNetworking library but i have also found this blog which seems to have a nice solution : http://www.isignmeout.com/multiple-nsurlconnections-viewcontroller/